# How should one use counter variables in Python without having to create them before use?

Tags: python, counter, locals

Let's say I have to loop over something and keep counters of various characteristics as the loop progresses. Before the loop, I could create these various counter variables with initial values.

```
count1 = 0
count2 = 0

for index in range(0, 10):
    count1 += 1
    count2 += 2

print count1, count2
```

Alternatively, I could create the counter variable when it is first actually used by using a conditional statement in the loop that creates the variable if it doesn't exist and then the variable is incremented.

```
for index in range(0, 10):
    if "count1" not in locals():
        count1 = 0
    if "count2" not in locals():
        count2 = 0        
    count1 += 1
    count2 += 2

print count1, count2
```

Is there a more compact or efficient way to do this?

Comment: Well, in the cases you list above, you could do `count1 = sum(1 for _ in range(10)` and `count2 = sum(2 for _ in range(10)`.

Comment: You can put them on one line if you want: `count1, count2 = 0, 0`

Comment: or count1 = count2 = 0

Comment: @MorganThrapp My variables are intended to be representative examples; I'm counting many things in the loop. The point of the two counters was to show that they are not both trivial and that there are multiple counters.

Comment: Then have a dictionary or list of counters, rather than separate names. It will make factoring out repetition much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother.  If you need a variable, define it.  It's going to happen one way or another.

---

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and then just increment various keys on the dict.  The keys will be initialized for you.  This is preferable to creating "variable variables".

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
counts[1] += 1
counts[2] += 2
```

---

If you want to count something as you iterate over it, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/).

```
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    print(i)
```

Both your counter examples could be easily derived from a single count this way.  (They could also just be derived from the length of the data).